# Why does pass in @State value not changed in child view?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Both View1 and View2 get the parameter **text** from the parent **ContentView**. But in View1 uses @Binding while View2 uses @State. Clicking View1 button will change the **text** value. However, after clicking, only the ContentView Text() updated, but View2's Text does not update? why is that so?

From the print-out, both view1 and view2 calls init with the new value *"View 1 Text"*.

Changing View2 to use @Binding will work to update View2's text when it's updated.

Here's the sample code:

ContentView.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showView1: Bool = false
    @State var showView2: Bool = false
    @State var text: String = "Hello World"

    init() {
        print("init ContentView")
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            Text("\(text)")

            HStack {
                if showView1 {
                    View1($text)
                }
                if showView2 {
                    View2(text)
                }
            }
            .border(.black)
            HStack {
                Button("View1") { showView1.toggle() }
                Button("View2") { showView2.toggle() }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

View1.swift

```
struct View1: View {
    @Binding var text: String
    init(_ text: Binding<String>) {
        self._text = text
        print("init View1  \(self.text)")
    }

    var body: some View {
        Button("Click") {
            print("Click view1 button")
            self.text = "View 1 Text"
        }
    }
}
```

View2.swift

```
struct View2: View {
    @State var text: String

    init(_ text: String) {
        self.text = text
        print("init View2  \(self.text)")
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Click") {
                print("Click view2 button")
            }
            Text("view2 text : \(text)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: does this answer your question:  https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui-concepts/driving-changes-in-your-ui-with-state-and-bindings

Comment: Consider watching WWDC 2019 [Data Flow Through SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/226/). The question is always “what is the source of truth”. And if you want `View2` to reflect changes in the `@State` of `ContentView`, then you would use a binding (as I think you concluded in your comment, “Changing View2 to use @Binding will work to update View2's text when it's updated”).

Answer (score -1):

`@State` in `View2` is a mistake it should be `let`, e.g.

```
struct View2: View {
    let text: String
```

`@State var` declares the source of truth, `let` passes down read access and `@Binding var` passes down read/write (binding is simply a pair of get/set closures). In either case when the value passed in is different from last time, `body` will be called. If you want to transform the value passed in, create a computed property in the child `View`. Use the `View` hierarchy to transform from rich model types to simple types that can easily be previewed.